# Pandas: drop rows with nan-valued index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given the following pandas DataFrame where some indices are `NaN`, how to drop the third and eight row since their index is `NaN`? Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np

data    = list('abcdefghil')
indices = [0, 1, np.nan, 3, 4, 5, 6, np.nan, 8, 9]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=indices, columns=['data'])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.dropna.html#pandas.Index.dropna) on the index:

```
In[68]:
df.loc[df.index.dropna()]

Out[68]: 
    data
0.0    a
1.0    b
3.0    d
4.0    e
5.0    f
6.0    g
8.0    i
9.0    l
```

Note that the presence of `NaN` makes the index `dtype` `float`, to change it to `int` cast the type:

```
In[70]:
df = df.loc[df.index.dropna()]
df.index = df.index.astype(int)
df

Out[70]: 
  data
0    a
1    b
3    d
4    e
5    f
6    g
8    i
9    l
```

You can also call `notnull` on the index would also work (somehow undocumented)

```
In[71]:
df = df.loc[df.index.notnull()]
df.index = df.index.astype(int)
df

Out[71]: 
  data
0    a
1    b
3    d
4    e
5    f
6    g
8    i
9    l
```

there is also [`isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isna.html#pandas.Index.isna):

```
In[78]:
df.loc[~df.index.isna()]

Out[78]: 
    data
0.0    a
1.0    b
3.0    d
4.0    e
5.0    f
6.0    g
8.0    i
9.0    l
```

and the more readable inverse [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.notna.html#pandas.Index.notna):

```
In[79]:
df.loc[df.index.notna()]

Out[79]: 
    data
0.0    a
1.0    b
3.0    d
4.0    e
5.0    f
6.0    g
8.0    i
9.0    l
```

As commented by @jpp you can use the top-level [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.notnull.html#pandas.notnull) also:

```
In[80]:
df.loc[pd.notnull(df.index)]

Out[80]: 
    data
0.0    a
1.0    b
3.0    d
4.0    e
5.0    f
6.0    g
8.0    i
9.0    l
```

There is also top-level `isna`, `notna`, and `isnull` but I'm not going to display those, you can check the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#top-level-missing-data)

Comment: `Index.dropna` / `Index.notnull` require Pandas >= 0.20.0, I believe (which is why I couldn't get it working). But otherwise `pd.notnull(df.index)` should work.

Comment: @jpp true but I'd assume that the `pandas` version would be recent enough

Comment: @jpp are you stuck on `<0.20.0`?

Comment: Yes, `0.19`, reasons beyond my control!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
 df = df[df.index.isnull() == False]
```

You might want to reset the index after

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.isnan` and taking the negative:

```
res = df[~np.isnan(df.index)]

print(res)

    data
0.0    a
1.0    b
3.0    d
4.0    e
5.0    f
6.0    g
8.0    i
9.0    l
```